# Intersection of 2 coin toss

Tags: probability

Folks, I have a basic question regarding the following. Two fair coins were tossed and it is known that at least one was a head. Find the probability that both were heads.

Solution:
E2 = Two heads {hh}
E1 = At least 1 head {hh,ht,th}
Universe = {hh,ht,th,tt}
Therefore, P(E2|E1) is what we need to find = P(E2 ∩ E1) / P(E1)

A book I'm reading says P(E2 ∩ E1) = 1/4 and P(E1) = 3/4.
The latter, P(E1), I understand.
The former I'm unclear on. Why is P(E2 ∩ E1) = 1/4 ?
Therefore the final answer becomes: (1/4)/(3/4) = 1/3

Thanks!

Comment: What is in the set $E2 \cap E1$? How many elements are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(E2\cap E1)=\frac{1}{4}$ because $E2 \cap E1$ is $\{ hh \}$, and $P(hh)=\frac{1}{4}$

Put a different way, for $E2 \cap E1$ to happen you need 2 heads and you need at least 1 head, but that is just the same as 2 heads, period. In other words, $E2 \cap E1 = E2$, so $P(E2 \cap E1) = P(E2) = \frac{1}{4}$

Also: I think the question is actually a little ambiguous. When you say 'it is known that at least one is head', how exactly is that known? Did you throw two coins, and you saw one of them land on heads, but the other one you didn't see? Because in that case, $P(E2|E1) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks Bram28 ! This confirms I'm an idiot...or suffering from sleep deprivation :)

Answer (score 0):

Intersection means common in both. Here in both E1 and E2 case with two heads is common. Only 1 case and total cases are 4. So we have $\frac 14$.